# Why doesn't flexbox item 'div' occupy whole line here?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a header on a website, and I'm using flexbox to make a layout.
I first make a container that will contain **header** and **main**. And initialize `display:flex` in the container thus header and main becomes flexbox items. And using `flex` property, I'm setting the proportion for both of them.

And in the **div id="header"**, which is a flexbox item of container, I also make this flexbox container, in which to make **div id="header-title"** a flexbox item of it.

But here is the problem.

**I'm assuming this 'header-title' flexbox item to occupy the whole line, but it actually doesn't. Why is this flexbox item not occupying the whole line?**

Isn't div [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) which occupy the whole line of the window?

Here's a code of mine and image that shows it doesn't occupy the whole line.

```css
   * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    a {
      /* This will inherit the color of its parent */
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #container {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    #header {
      background: yellow;
      min-height: 100px;
      flex: 1.5 1 0;

      display: flex;
    }

    #main {
      background: blue;
      flex: 8.5 1 0;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header-title">
        <div id="header-first-row">Daegudude's Calculator</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      MAIN
    </div>
  </div> <!-- container -->
```

[image: rendered result]

Comment: Yes, `<div>` defaults to being a block-level element, but that's only a **default** - and defaults no-longer apply when an element participates in a flexbox or grid formatting context.

Comment: Use `#container { align-items: stretch; }` (as opposed to `justify-content` because this is a `flex-direction: column;`